WordPress: How to fix "404 Not found" error for page set to private?
I ran several page tools which returned all the "404 not found" pages from Wordpress website.
All of the affected pages are set to private and referenced by page_id=310 links.
How can I get rid of the links with page_id=310????
Thank you.

You can search for these strings in the database and then replace them as per your need.
You can use Search & Replace Plugin once this plugin is activated you can go to Toots > Search & Replace and here you can provide details as per your need.

